# Using Euler's form to help solve a limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Say if I have the limit as $w$ approaches $0$ of $\frac{\bar{w}}{w}$, I can set $w = re^{i\theta}$, which would give the limit as $w$ approaches $0$ of $e^{-2i\theta}$. Am I correct in assuming that this limit doesn't exist since as $w$ approaches $0$, $r$ tends to $0$ and $\theta$ can range between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ so the limit as $w$ approaches $0$ will always take different values?

What if though I had $r$ infront of the $e^{-2i\theta}$, i.e. I had $re^{-2i\theta}$ as $w$ approaches $0$. I would have again that $r$ approaches $0$ and $\theta$ can range between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, so since $r$ approaches $0$ surely the limit would tend to $0$ and so always exist?

Comment: You are correct the limit does not exist.

Comment: @user Thank you. What about for the case when for a random limit I end up with $re^{-2i \theta}$ as $w$ tends to $0$. Am I right in assuming that this limit tends to $0$ as even though $\theta$ takes any values between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, since $r=0$, the limit is always equal to $0$ regardless of the value fo $\theta$?

Comment: Yes, it is equal to $0$.